# Game character split health bar calculation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

I'm trying to make a health bar for a character in a game and I want to split it into multiple smaller bars.

I've been working all morning on it, but somehow I cannot figure out how to do it.
Here's the code I made until now:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// UI list for the health bars
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] private List<Slider> healthBars = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// The health of the boss
    /// </summary>
    [SerializeField] private Enemy bossLife = null;

private void Awake()
    {
        InitializeUI();
    }

private void LateUpdate()
    {
        UpdateBossUI();
    }

// WIP
private void InitializeUI()
    {
        int _maxBossHealth = bossLife.maxHealth;
        int _totalHeathBars = healthBars.Count;

        float _barMaxVal = _maxBossHealth / _totalHeathBars;
        for (int i = 0; i < _totalHeathBars; i++)
        {
            healthBars[i].value = healthBars[i].maxValue = _barMaxVal;
        }
        lastHealth = _maxBossHealth;
    }

    private void UpdateBossUI()
    {
        // Be sure to not update the UI every frame but only if needed
        int _currBossHealth = bossLife.CurrentHealth;
        if (lastHealth == _currBossHealth)
            return;

        // Remember when the UI was updated
        lastHealth = _currBossHealth;

        int _maxBossHealth = bossLife.maxHealth;
        int _totalHeathBars = healthBars.Count;
        float _barMaxVal = _maxBossHealth / _totalHeathBars;

        for (int i = 0; i < _totalHeathBars; i++)
        {
            if (_currBossHealth > _maxBossHealth - _barMaxVal * (i + 1) 
                && _currBossHealth <= _maxBossHealth - _barMaxVal * i)
            {
                healthBars[i].value = ((_maxBossHealth - (_maxBossHealth / _totalHeathBars)) - _currBossHealth) * -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Can someone please give me a little hand?
Thanks

Comment: Could you add a little illustration how this will look like? Alone from the code it is a bit hard for me to imagine

Comment: Basically you have a list of progress bars (n) and the boss starts with an amount of life.
Each bar has a max value that can be set, so what you do is to set his max value to boss max health divided from all bars
Example:
bossLife = 100;
progressBar.count = 3;
each progressBar.maxValue = 100 / 3;
When the boss is damaged his life is starting to decreasing and the UI is updating in real-time.
If the first progress bar is empty, the second one next to list start decreasing and so on.
My problem is to calculate the health value of the boss to apply for each bar properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change your last `for` loop to this:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < _totalHeathBars; i++)
    {
        if (_currBossHealth >= (i + 1) * _barMaxVal)     // health greater than current bar => full bar
            healthBars[i].value = _barMaxVal;
        else if (_currBossHealth < i * _barMaxVal)       // health less than current bar => empty bar
            healthBars[i].value = 0;
        else                                             // health inside current bar 
            healthBars[i].value = _currBossHealth % _barMaxVal;
    }
```

Comment: OMG thank you so much! This code is so clean!
I thought to use modulo operator but for some reason, I couldn't figure it out.